# error running quorra: quorra is not recognized

Tags: node.js, quorrajs

I received an app that uses quorra, so I installed quorra via the instructions on the webpage

```
λ npm install -g quorra-cli
C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\quorra -> C:\Users\****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quorra-cli\quorra.js
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\quorra-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

+ quorra-cli@1.0.0
added 209 packages from 124 contributors in 18.942s
```

But then when I try to run anything, like

```
quorra ride
quorra new
quorra -v
```

I get:

```
'quorra' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

It seems like it cant find where to run the quorra command, but I installed it so I dont understand what else I am supposed to do I didnt find anything else on the docs.
I even tried adding the quora folder 
C:\Users****\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\quorra-cli
into my path variable but no luck

Any help?

Comment: I just installed it on Ubuntu and it worked fine.

Comment: i am running on windows get this error

Comment: Quorra framework is not actively maintained. It will work for up to Node JS version 6.

Comment: oh what do i do then I am running v10.13.0

Comment: I also tried it on my friend's laptop. worked fine. He uses Windows 10 btw

Comment: Any idea what I am doing wrong??? Do you get the same message at install as I do??? All i did was run npm install -g quorra-cli and then any of the 3 commands listed above gave me an error.

Comment: ran my CLI as admin quorra works now, thanks!

Comment: yes, I got exactly the same message. my node version is: 8.12.0 if that helps.